# Parameterized query for linked server

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

Hi i followed an example for parameterizing openqueries and this was one of the options to avoid all the ugly quotes.

```
DECLARE @uap NVARCHAR(50) 
SELECT @uap = 'UAP1'    
EXEC MACPAC.master.dbo.sp_executesql
N'SELECT RD6001 as Referencia,
         RD6002 as UAP,
         RD6030 as QTD_AB_PDP_W01, 
         RD6031 AS QTD_AB_PDP_W02 
FROM D805DATPOR.TRP060D 
WHERE RD6001 not like ''%OP%''
AND RD6001 not like ''%PT%'' 
AND RD6002 = @uap',
N'@uap nvarchar(50)',
@uap
```

this is the example

```
DECLARE @VAR char(2)
SELECT  @VAR = 'CA'
EXEC MyLinkedServer.master.dbo.sp_executesql
N'SELECT * FROM pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = @state',
N'@state char(2)',
@VAR
```

however my approach does not work

> OLE DB provider "IBMDA400" for linked server "MACPAC" returned message "SQL0104: Token { was not valid. Valid tokens: ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN.
>   Cause . . . . . :   A syntax error was detected at token {.  Token { is not a valid token.  A partial list of valid tokens is ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK OPEN WITH ALTER BEGIN.  This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the token.  The error may be earlier in the statement, but the syntax of the statement appears to be valid up to this point. Recovery  . . . :   Do one or more of the following and try the request again: -- Verify the SQL statement in the area of the token {. Correct the statement.  The error could be a missing comma or quotation mark, it could be a misspelled word, or it could be related to the order of clauses. -- If the error token is , correct the SQL statement because it does not end with a valid clause.".
>   Msg 7212, Level 17, State 1, Line 8
>   Could not execute procedure 'sp_executesql' on remote server 'MACPAC'.

UPDATE

I forgot to mention that the linked server provider is IBM, so I guess it's in ORACLE, which I didn't know about this detail.

Here is the suggested approach for executing parameterized queries to linked server which is ORACLE

```
DECLARE @UAP NVARCHAR(50)
SET @UAP = 'UAP1'
EXEC ('SELECT RD6001 as Referencia,
       RD6002 as UAP,
       RD6030 as QTD_AB_PDP_W01 
       FROM D805DATPOR.TRP060D 
       where RD6001 not like ''%OP%'' 
       and RD6001 not like ''%PT%'' 
       and RD6002 = ?', @UAP) 
AT MACPAC
```

For more parameters, just add column name and add another `?`

This works perfectly and it's very clean!

Comment: Considering it's a linked server, what's wrong with `DECLARE @VAR char(2) = 'CA'; SELECT * FROM MyLinkedServer.pubs.dbo.authors WHERE state = @VAR;`?

Comment: I cannot access it this way SELECT * FROM MACPAC.D805DATPOR.dbo.TRP060D WHERE RD6002 = 'UAP1'

Comment: Why not @Jackal ? If you can't access the server via that query, why do you think `sp_executesql` would work?

Comment: I'm not sure, i cannot see it's datatables since the provider is IBM so I assume i need open query to access different providers

Comment: `sp_executesql` only exists on SQL Server, so this won't work against an IBM database. What should work is `EXEC ('query with ? parameters', value) AT [macpac]`, if the linked server is enabled for pass-through queries. Note that you must use the ODBC parameter passing approach here (with `?` and passing parameters in strict order) since named parameters, again, require a SQL Server counterpart. The docs [have an example for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql#j-using-execute-to-query-an-oracle-database-on-a-linked-server).

Comment: Thanks alot ! My coworkers have been working with openqueries all the time and using replace function to duplicate quotes and it is really dirty to work with! Tried this way and it worked perfectly and it's clean

Comment: To be clear, Oracle is just an example of a provider. You've definitely got an IBM DB2 server, but the `EXEC ... AT` approach works for any provider (unless they don't support parameters at all, I suppose).

Comment: Also is there any difference between using this or openquery in terms of performance or restrictions?

Comment: Yes -- for starters, all database servers have different behavior for queries where you use parameters as opposed to queries where you substitute in literals. This can be both positive (plan reuse) and negative (*improper* plan reuse). In *general*, though, using proper parameterization would be a good thing. More pertinently, `OPENQUERY` can be used at any time you would use a table (in a `FROM`) -- `EXEC .. AT` cannot, it can only be used standalone, so it cannot completely replace `OPENQUERY`.

Comment: I see so it is not possible to use exec at with joins and so on and still have to rely on dynamic SQL. Still this is a great alternative when they are not needed